# Is it possible to unlock the grub boot with a usb key?

Tags: grub, slackware

I have successfully setup a Slackware with boot encrypted partition
Grub ask me for luks password and decrypt the boot, then my ROOT partition encrypted read from a usb key a file and decrypt the ROOT partition

Is it possible to unlock the grub boot with a usb key?

For the procedure follow [this guide](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/a-concept-guide-on-luks-raid-1-and-encrypted-boot-with-grub-for-slackware-current-4175673477/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

- **NO** with official GRUB
- **YES** with [this fork](http://grub.johnlane.ie/)

The only problem is this fork don't alter the grub-mkconfig command
so grub.cfg must be edited manually